# Ruby syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I have been playing around on CodeCademy with some Ruby since yesterday, and I feel as though I am grasping it slightly, but a few issues are becoming visible.

What is wrong with this code? I keep getting an error:

> (ruby):15: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

```
print "What grade did you get on your final?"
grade = gets.chomp
if grade > 1
    puts "You're just making that up! Really?"
answer = gets.chomp
yes = true
no = false

if answer == true
    print "Oh, that's awesome!"
if answer == false
    print "Dang, I thought you were serious."
else
    print "What? I don't understand."
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please make sure you visit the [tour] page and the [ask] page.

Answer (score 2):

It becomes clear with proper indentation

```
print "What grade did you get on your final?"
grade = gets.chomp
if grade > 1
  puts "You're just making that up! Really?"
  answer = gets.chomp
  yes = true
  no = false

  if answer == true
    print "Oh, that's awesome!"
    if answer == false
      print "Dang, I thought you were serious."
    else
      print "What? I don't understand."
    end
```

Every `if` in Ruby needs a corresponding `end`. You have three `if`s and only one `end`. So only the last `if answer == false` has a matching `end`, you need two more for the others.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `if` statements that do not have a corresponding `end`.

```
if grade > 1
  puts "You're just making that up! Really?"
end
```

and

```
if answer == true
  print "Oh, that's awesome!"
end
```

On an unrelated note, I believe you want `puts` instead of `print`.

Also, when you have a boolean value, you do not need to do

```
if my_boolean == true
  # do something
end
```

It is the exact same thing as doing

```
if my_boolean
  # do something
end
```

And lastly, boolean values only have two possible values, `true` and `false`. That last `else` statement you have does not make sense, because it will be activated whenever `answer == true`, which you already have a case for.

Comment: I got it to work by doing this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=pFZpG4qv (Paste of the code) but still not sure how to make the else statement work. I want it to say "What? I don't understand." if the user puts anything other than yes or no. I considered the || function, but not sure how that would work properly.

Comment: You want to compare with what the user said. `answer == 'yes'` then you can do an `elsif answer == 'no'`, then you can use your `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need an end to each `if` that you have.
You can do something like this:

```
puts "What grade did you get on your final?"
grade = gets.chomp

if grade > 1
  puts "You're just making that up! Really?"
end

answer = gets.chomp

if answer == "yes"
  print "Oh, that's awesome!"
elsif answer == "no"
  print "Dang, I thought you were serious."
else
  print "What? I don't understand."
end
```

or can be like this, where you don´t need to use the `end`

```
puts "What grade did you get on your final?"
grade = gets.chomp

# HERE
puts "You're just making that up! Really?" if grade > 1

answer = gets.chomp

if answer == "yes"
  print "Oh, that's awesome!"
elsif answer == "no"
  print "Dang, I thought you were serious."
else
  print "What? I don't understand."
end
```